# Bundle layout using d3.js and given json file structure

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js, bundle-layout

I have a json file with elements like this:

```
[{
    "name": "Manuel Jose",
    "ttags": ["vivant", "designer", "artista", "empreendedor"]
}]
```

I'm trying to get the node and the edges using this structure to complete a graph like:

[image]

(diagram is taken from [d3.js documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Bundle-Layout))

Both `name` and `ttags` in my json file refer to nodes, `ttags` are actually links between the node and another nodes.

But, I cannot understand how to create this diagram using this library d3 and above json file.

```
    d3.json("/data/tedxufrj.json", function(classes) {
      var nodes = cluster.nodes(package.root(classes)),
          links = package.imports(nodes);

      vis.selectAll("path.link")
          .data(splines = bundle(links))
        .enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", line);

      vis.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
        .append("text")
          .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? 8 : -8; })
          .attr("dy", ".31em")
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? null : "rotate(180)"; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
    });
```

And this is file package.js:

```
        (function() {
              packages = {

                // Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
                root: function(classes) {
                  var map = {};

                  function find(name, data) {
                    var node = map[name], i;  
                    if (!node) {
                      node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
                      if (name.length) {
                        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
                        node.parent.children.push(node);
                        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
                      }
                    }
                    return node;
                  }

                  classes.forEach(function(d) {
                    find(d.name, d);
                  });

                  return map[""];
                },

                // Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
                imports: function(nodes) {
                  var map = {},
                      imports = [];

                  // Compute a map from name to node.
                  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    map[d.name] = d;
                  });

                  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
                  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                    if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
                      imports.push({source: map[d.name], target: map[i]});
                    });
                  });

                  return imports;
                }

              };
            })();
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: http://testprogramming.googlecode.com/svn-history/r391/trunk/javascript/svg/d3/test/flare-imports.json

This example shows the data structure required by the bundle layout.
Orginally the data structure is hierarchical like the visualization in this graph: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html

What I would do in your place is to add fictional root to make a hierarchy, like this:

```
[
{"name": "root.Manuel_Jose", "imports": ["root.vivant", "root.designer", "root.artista", "root.empreendedor"]},
{"name": "root.vivant", "imports": []},
{"name": "root.designer", "imports": []},
{"name": "root.artista", "imports": []},
{"name": "root.empreendedor", "imports": []}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

@wceo, the root is not actually required. It is optional and is used the create a visual separation.

@VividD, what you need to do is to create nodes for "vivant", "designer", "artista", "empreendedor", linking back to themselves.

I know it's weird but that is what's required.

so your json should look like this:

```
[
  {"name": "Manuel Jose", "ttags": ["vivant", "designer", "artista", "empreendedor"]},
  {"name": "vivant", "ttags": ["vivant"]},
  {"name": "designer", "ttags": ["designer"]},
  {"name": "artista", "ttags": ["artista"]},
  {"name": "empreendedor", "ttags": ["empreendedor"]}
]
```

Comment: Hi how to use csv or other files for this?